# AS3 Error #1010 in function

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I got an error #1010 in a function, and I was wondering where the error specifically was? Thanks!

```
public function getSide(point:Point,mag:Number):int
    {
        if (level.map[int(point.x - mag / 32)][int(point.y / 32)].typ != 2)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else if (level.map[int(point.x / 32)][int(point.y+mag / 32)].typ!=2)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (level.map[int(point.x+mag / 32)][int(point.y / 32)].typ!=2)
        {
            return 2;
        }
        else if (level.map[int(point.x / 32)][int(point.y-mag / 32)].typ!=2)
        {
            return 3;
        }else{
            return getSide(point,mag+1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: check if `level` and `point` objects exist/defined

Comment: point is defined in the function

Comment: 100% it is not defined in `getSide` function

Answer (score 0):

error #1010 is thrown when a term is undefined, such as a value or method. I'm going to take a guess and say it is the `.typ` call that is causing the error, because you are retrieving an untyped object from the two dimensional level.map array.

For each if-else, try casting the object retrieval before calling `.typ`. For example, replace this:

```
level.map[int(point.x - mag / 32)][int(point.y / 32)].typ != 2
```

With this:

```
(level.map[int(point.x - mag / 32)][int(point.y / 32)] as MyClass).typ != 2
```

Obviously replace `MyClass` with the name of the class you want to cast to.

On a separate note, be aware that `point.x - mag / 32` will be calculated as `point.x - (mag / 32)` as per the standard [Order of Operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations). I'm not sure if this is what you intended, but wanted to point it out.